# Como llamar dos vistas en una de asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Amigos quien me puede colaborar lo que pasa es que quiero llenas dos formularios de  diferentes vistas en uno sola vista de Asp.Net
Gracias!

Comment: Debieras reformular tu pregunta y mostrar lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer uso de ViewModels ya que las vistas de asp.net basadas en modelo solo admiten uno a la vez, en tu caso deberías crear un viewmodel que contenga los campos de ambos modelos involucrados y entonces crear tu formulario basado en el viewmodel. te recomiendo le eches un vistazo a esta respuesta donde lo exolico más detallado, espero te sea de utilidad  [[Formulario Multiple ASP MVC](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75733/formulario-multiple-asp-mvc/75938#75938][1])